# proving the result $g(c)=\bigg(\frac{g(x_{1})+g(x_{2})+g(x_{3})}{3}\bigg)$

Tags: calculus

> Let $g$ be a continuous function defined on $[a,b].$ Let $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\in(a,b).$ Then prove that there exists a real number $c\in[a,b]$ such that $\displaystyle g(c)=\bigg(\frac{g(x_{1})+g(x_{2})+g(x_{3})}{3}\bigg)$

What i try

Using lagrange  mean value theorem

For $[x_{1},x_{2}]$

$$g'(c_{1})=\frac{g(x_{2})-g(x_{1})}{x_{2}-x_{1}}$$

Where $c_{1}\in(x_{1},x_{2})$

For $[x_{2},x_{3}]$

$$g'(c_{2})=\frac{g(x_{3})-g(x_{2})}{x_{3}-x_{2}}$$

Where $c_{2}\in(x_{2},x_{3})$

From here i did not undrstand how to solve it

Help me please

Comment: Your function is continuous but not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: You cannot use the mean value theorem if $g$ is not differntiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Raskolnikov](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3567/raskolnikov)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589940/proving-the-result-gc-bigg-fracgx-1gx-2gx-33-bigg/3589943#comment7380841_3589940) states, you can't necessarily assume $g(x)$ is differentiable. Instead, by the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem), since $g(x)$ is defined and continuous on the closed set $[a,b]$, it's also bounded on that set, with those bounds each being reached at least once. Let $M_1$ be the lower bound and $M_2$ be the upper bound. Then you have that

$$M_1 \le g(x_1) \le M_2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
$$M_1 \le g(x_2) \le M_2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
$$M_1 \le g(x_3) \le M_2 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Adding these $3$ inequalities gives

$$3M_1 \le g(x_1) + g(x_2) + g(x_3) \le 3M_2 \implies M_1 \le \frac{g(x_1) + g(x_2) + g(x_3)}{3} \le M_2 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, by the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), there's a $c \in [a,b]$ such that

$$g(c)=\left(\frac{g(x_{1})+g(x_{2})+g(x_{3})}{3}\right) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$